# Actualizar registros si el codigo esta en una lista de Resultados SQL Server

Tags: sql, transact-sql

necesito ayuda con un código. Estoy tratando de actualizar un campo, regitro en una Tabla de SQL Server. Si este registro se encuentra en en un resultado.
Pero Siempre me muestra el siguiente error:

"Sólo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS"

CODIGO:

```
  UPDATE TABLA1
   SET vchCodigoEstado='14' WHERE Codigo IN
   (SELECT P.Codigo, PL.Fecha FROM TABLAPUB P
   inner Join  TABLAFEC PL on P.Codigo=PL.Codigo
   Where PL.Fecha >= Getdate() and P.chrEstado='0')
```

Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que tienes 2 columnas en la subconsulta. Tienes que dejar solo la columna de código.

```
UPDATE TABLA1
SET vchCodigoEstado='14' 
WHERE Codigo IN (SELECT P.Codigo 
                FROM TABLAPUB P
                INNER JOIN  TABLAFEC PL ON P.Codigo = PL.Codigo
                WHERE PL.Fecha >= GETDATE() 
                AND   P.chrEstado = '0');
```

En caso de que necesites unir validar por las dos columnas en Tabla1, puedes usar `EXISTS()`.

```
UPDATE T
SET vchCodigoEstado='14' 
FROM TABLA1 T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM TABLAPUB P
                INNER JOIN  TABLAFEC PL ON P.Codigo = PL.Codigo
                WHERE PL.Fecha    >= GETDATE() 
                AND   P.chrEstado =  '0'
                AND   P.Codigo    =  T.Codigo
                AND   PL.Fecha    =  T.Fecha); --Asumiendo que tienes la columna fecha en Tabla1
```

Comment: Correcto, Ya lo corregi. Muchas gracias funciona muy bien

Answer (score 1):

El error que estás encontrando se debe a que estás seleccionando múltiples columnas (P.Codigo y PL.Fecha) en tu subconsulta, pero estás utilizando la cláusula IN en tu consulta principal, que solo espera una sola columna como resultado de la subconsulta.

Para solucionar este problema, debes modificar tu consulta de la siguiente manera

> ```
> UPDATE TABLA1
> SET vchCodigoEstado = '14'
> WHERE Codigo IN (
>     SELECT P.Codigo
>     FROM TABLAPUB P
>     INNER JOIN TABLAFEC PL ON P.Codigo = PL.Codigo
>     WHERE PL.Fecha >= GETDATE() AND P.chrEstado = '0'
> )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Ya te han explicado cual es el error y como solucionarlos. Yo te presento una solución que podría ser más eficiente si tienes un conjunto de datos grande:

```
UPDATE T
SET vchCodigoEstado = '14'
FROM TABLA1 T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT P.Codigo
    FROM TABLAPUB P
    INNER JOIN TABLAFEC PL ON P.Codigo = PL.Codigo
    WHERE PL.Fecha >= GETDATE() AND P.chrEstado = '0'
) AS SUBQ ON T.Codigo = SUBQ.Codigo;
```

En este caso, en lugar de emplear la cláusula IN para realizar la coincidencia de registros entre las tablas, se utiliza un INNER JOIN junto con una subconsulta que selecciona únicamente los códigos que cumplen con la condición especificada. Esta estrategia permite reducir la cantidad de registros procesados y potencialmente mejorar el rendimiento en situaciones donde se manejan conjuntos de datos extensos.

También te dejare un pequeña variacion que seria util. Usar `SELECT 1` en lugar de `SELECT *` para devolver `1` que seria mas eficiente que devolver todos los registros.

```
UPDATE T
SET vchCodigoEstado='14' 
FROM TABLA1 T
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TABLAPUB P
    INNER JOIN TABLAFEC PL ON P.Codigo = PL.Codigo
    WHERE PL.Fecha >= GETDATE() 
    AND P.chrEstado = '0'
    AND P.Codigo = T.Codigo
);
```